# How do i fix subquery returns more than 1 row error

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am executing this query

```
$sql=mysql_query("SELECT c.*,
  (SELECT Count(b.text) From tbl_people_comment  Where b.idsms=c.id AND b.visible=1) AS ccomment
FROM tbl_peoplesms AS c
INNER JOIN tbl_people_comment AS b ON b.idsms= c.id
WHERE c.visible=1
GROUP BY c.id");
```

I am trying to make it return something like this in php

```
 [
      {
      "id":"20", 
      "name":"test",
      "text":"test",
      "visible":"1",
      "ccomment":"5"
      },

      {
      "id":"19",
      "name":"test",
      "text":"test",
      "visible":"1"
      "ccomment":"7" 
      }
    ]
```

i use this code to show it

```
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)) 
$output[]=$row; 
print(json_encode($output, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE));
```

However, I am getting the error Subquery returns more than 1 row.

this is tbl_peoplesms
[tbl_peoplesms](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SL96x.jpg)

and tbl_people_comment
[tbl_people_comment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/trI2K.jpg)

Comment: So you need to rewrite the subquery to only return one row. The simple solution is to add `LIMIT 1` to the subquery, but given that it seems you didn't expect multiple rows to be returning, you may have issues elsewhere. Though looking at your query it doesn't look possible that it could return more than one row.. Are you sure this is the right query?

Comment: I add my tables.Can you write a query for me?

Comment: Actually the query in your question should NOT give you the error mentioned. Because your subquery is a `select count()` without a `group by`... You did not give us the original erroneous code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using an inline subquery, just left join tbl_people_comment on tbl_peoplesms and move the `b.visible=1` condition into the join clause:

```
SELECT c.name, count(b.text) as ccomment
FROM tbl_peoplesms AS c
LEFT JOIN tbl_people_comment AS b ON b.idsms= c.id and b.visible=1
GROUP BY c.name
```

If you would like to include more fields from the tbl_people_comment table in the select list, then add them to the group by clause as well.